# A star algorithm with multiple goals

Tags: a-star

Instead of a typical "patch finding problem" within a Maze. I'm asked to implement a "catching all flags within a maze" problem using A star algorithm.
For example: (s->start point f->flag)
`############
 #.....f###.#
 #.########f#
 #....f...#.#
 #s######...#
 ############`

I understand A star algorithm can find the best solution from start point to goal. But what if we have multiple goals like this example indicates? How should I find the fastest solution to catch all the flag using A star algorithm?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try ? We are not a free coding community

Comment: This has been asked many times before.  See for example [A-star: heuristic for multiple goals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637827/a-star-heuristic-for-multiple-goals)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question, as it's asking about finding a route that's visiting **all** the targets, instead of to the nearest target.